# How to generate a tone with ramp-up / ramp-down in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to generate a tone in Matlab at 1.5 KHz with peak amplitude of 30 mPa and a duration of 25 ms, with 1 ms ramp-up and ramp-down at the onset and offset, respectively.

So far I have a tone (P) with the code:

```
fs = 100000;
CF = 1.5*10^3;
amp = 30*10^-3;
duration=25*10^-3;
values = 0:1/fs:duration;
tone=[amp*sin(2*pi*CF*values)]';
```

This seems like an easy job, but I can't figure it out. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Could you specify what's your problem specifically and how far you've come on your own? Would you know how to generate a 1.5 kHz tone if it were not for the ramps (using, e.g., the `sin` function)?

Comment: @Florian Oops, I thought I had copied that in as well. My head is tired :-) I have added it to the question. I can't figure out how to add the ramps to the tone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the ramp envelope first and then apply it to the `tone`. (using element-wise multiply `.*`).

Try something along these lines:

```matlab
% generate ramps
% duration of 1ms with fs=100000 is 100 samples:
ramp_up = [1:100]/100
ramp_down = 1 - ramp_up

% apply to tone
tone[1:100] = tone[1:100] .* ramp_up
tone[end-100+1:end] = tone[end-100+1:end] .* ramp_down
```